# Adjust the where statement based on the columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query like this, I need to adjust my where statement based on the columns, please look at the following query:

```
SELECT 
    b.id as [ID]
    ,d.[Title] as [Title]
    ,e.Class as [Class]

    ,Sum(a.col1) as [Last 30 Days Col1]
    ,Sum(a.col2) as [Last 30 Days Col2]

    ,Sum(a.col1) as [Last 90 Days Col1]
    ,Sum(a.col2) as [Last 90 Days Col2]

    ,Sum(a.col1) as [Last 365 Days Col1]
    ,Sum(a.col2) as [Last 365 Days Col2]
FROM 
    tb1 a
INNER JOIN 
    tb2 b -- ON anything
INNER JOIN 
    tb3 c -- ON anything
INNER JOIN       
    tb4 d -- ON anything
INNER JOIN 
    tb5 e -- ON anything
WHERE
    a.DateCol >= DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())
GROUP BY
    b.id, d.Title, e.Class
```

What I am currently getting as the result is like this:

> WHEN:
>
> where a.DateCol >= DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE())   => Last 30 Days Col1 = Last 90 Days Col1 = Last 365 Days Col1 = 10
>
> WHEN:
>
> where a.DateCol >= DATEADD(QUARTER,-1,GETDATE())   => Last 30 Days Col1 = Last 90 Days Col1 = Last 365 Days Col1 = 100
>
> WHEN:
>
> where a.DateCol >= DATEADD(YEAR,-1,GETDATE())   => Last 30 Days Col1 = Last
>   90 Days Col1 = Last 365 Days Col1 = 1000

```
ID | Title |  Class | Last 30 Days Col1 | Last 30 Days Col2 | Last 90 Days Col1 | Last 90 Days Col2 | Last 365 Days Col1 | Last 365 Days Col2
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 | T1    |  C1    |        10         |         20        |         10        |         20        |         10          |        20
```

But as you guess, I need the correct value will be displayed per column, I don't know how can I change my query to achieve this, since I have a fixed where statement. Any thought on how can I adjust my where statement based on 30,90 and 365 days and show the correct values in correct columns accordingly?

Comment: You have put condition in sum instead of where clause like : 
sum(CASE WHEN a.DateCol >= DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE()) THEN a.col1 ELSE 0 END)  
similarly for next columns

Comment: @SundarSingh Thanks your solution is working as expected. Would you please post an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2):

First, where condition should filter all records from last year `where a.DateCol >= DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())` then in your Sum function, you put days diff to condition:

```
SELECT b.id AS [ID]
    ,d.[Title] AS [Title]
    ,e.Class AS [Class]
    ,Sum(WHERE datediff(day, a.DateCol, getdate()) <= 30 then a.Col1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Last 30 Days Col1]
    ,Sum(WHERE datediff(day, a.DateCol, getdate()) <= 30 then a.col2 ELSE 0 END) AS [Last 30 Days Col2]
    ,Sum(WHERE datediff(day, a.DateCol, getdate()) <= 90 then a.Col1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Last 90 Days Col1]
    ,Sum(WHERE datediff(day, a.DateCol, getdate()) <= 90 then a.col2 ELSE 0 END) AS [Last 90 Days Col2]
    ,Sum(WHERE datediff(day, a.DateCol, getdate()) <= 365 then a.Col1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Last 365 Days Col1]
    ,Sum(WHERE datediff(day, a.DateCol, getdate()) <= 356 then a.col2 ELSE 0 END) AS [Last 365 Days Col2]
FROM tb1 a
INNER JOIN tb2 b -- ON anything
INNER JOIN tb3 c -- ON anything
INNER JOIN tb4 d -- ON anything
INNER JOIN tb5 e -- ON anything
WHERE a.DateCol >= DATEADD(YEAR, - 1, GETDATE())
GROUP BY b.id
    ,d.Title
    ,e.Class
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems removing the condition from the where clause and put it in columns instead is working fine, exactly like what @SundarSingh said.

Comment: Condition in where statement is fine, because there may be millions of records that are older than 365 days, so it is reasonable to filter them first and then apply in-Sum conditions

Comment: So you mean this way is more efficient?

Comment: @Jim yes it makes sense and filtering last 1 year records.