# The query is executing very slowly, is there any way to improve it any further?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the following query, and because of a lot of `SUM` function calls, my query is running too slow. I have a lot of records in my database and I would like to get a report from the current year and last year (Last 30 days, Last 90 days and last 365 days) for each one:

```sql
SELECT 
    b.id as [ID]
    ,d.[Title] as [Title]
    ,e.Class as [Class]

    ,Sum(CASE WHEN a.DateCol >= DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE()) THEN a.col1 ELSE 0 END) as [Current - Last 30 Days Col1]
    ,Sum(CASE WHEN a.DateCol >= DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE()) THEN a.col2 ELSE 0 END) as [Current - Last 30 Days Col2]

    ,Sum(CASE WHEN a.DateCol >= DATEADD(QUARTER,-1,GETDATE()) THEN a.col1 ELSE 0 END) as [Current - Last 90 Days Col1]
    ,Sum(CASE WHEN a.DateCol >= DATEADD(QUARTER,-1,GETDATE()) THEN a.col2 ELSE 0 END) as [Current - Last 90 Days Col2]

    ,Sum(CASE WHEN a.DateCol >= DATEADD(YEAR,-1,GETDATE()) THEN a.col1 ELSE 0 END) as [Current - Last 365 Days Col1]
    ,Sum(CASE WHEN a.DateCol >= DATEADD(YEAR,-1,GETDATE()) THEN a.col2 ELSE 0 END) as [Current - Last 365 Days Col2]

    ,Sum(CASE WHEN a.DateCol >= DATEADD(MONTH,-13,GETDATE()) and a.DateCol <= DATEADD(MONTH,-12,GETDATE()) THEN a.col1 ELSE 0 END) as [Last year - Last 30 Days Col1]
    ,Sum(CASE WHEN a.DateCol >= DATEADD(MONTH,-13,GETDATE()) and a.DateCol <= DATEADD(MONTH,-12,GETDATE()) THEN a.col2 ELSE 0 END) as [Last year - Last 30 Days Col2]

    ,Sum(CASE WHEN a.DateCol >= DATEADD(QUARTER,-5,GETDATE()) and a.DateCol <= DATEADD(QUARTER,-4,GETDATE()) THEN a.col1 ELSE 0 END) as [Last year - Last 90 Days Col1]
    ,Sum(CASE WHEN a.DateCol >= DATEADD(QUARTER,-5,GETDATE()) and a.DateCol <= DATEADD(QUARTER,-4,GETDATE()) THEN a.col2 ELSE 0 END) as [Last year - Last 90 Days Col2]

    ,Sum(CASE WHEN a.DateCol >= DATEADD(YEAR,-2,GETDATE()) and a.DateCol <= DATEADD(YEAR,-1,GETDATE()) THEN a.col1 ELSE 0 END) as [Last year - Last 365 Days Col1]
    ,Sum(CASE WHEN a.DateCol >= DATEADD(YEAR,-2,GETDATE()) and a.DateCol <= DATEADD(YEAR,-1,GETDATE()) THEN a.col2 ELSE 0 END) as [Last year - Last 365 Days Col2]


    FROM 
    tb1 a
INNER JOIN 
    tb2 b on a.id=b.fid and a.col3 = b.col4
INNER JOIN 
    tb3 c on b.fid = c.col5
INNER JOIN       
    tb4 d on c.id = d.col6
INNER JOIN 
    tb5 e on c.col7 = e.id
GROUP BY
    b.id, d.Title, e.Class
```

Does anyone have any idea how can I improve my query in order to run faster?

**EDIT:** I was encouraged to move the `DATEADD` function call to the `where` statement and load first two years first then filter them in columns, but I am not sure the suggested answer is executed and works, it could be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59944426/12536284

If you agree with the above solution, please show me how can I apply it in my current query?

Just FYI, I am using this SP in C#, Entity Framework (DB-First), something like this:

```cs
var result = MyDBEntities.CalculatorSP();
```

Comment: Show us your execution plan...

Comment: _ON anything_ - is what can make query slow

Comment: @Fabio No that could not be the cause of the issue because already tested it without the SUM functions. I guess a lot of `DATEADD` and `Sum` functions calls could be the reason but not sure how can I improve them.

Comment: @Jim the execution plan will *show* you where the time is being spent and allow you to improve it. You can't just guess.

Comment: You don't need to call `GETDATE()` every time. Declare variable and use it instead of function call: `DECLARE @currentDate as date; SET @currentDate = GETDATE();`.

Comment: Are those inner joins without on's intentional? Also, you might try running the query without ANY of the SUM functions to get a count of how many records you're expecting to see after a successful run.

Comment: @RomanDoskoch Did what you said, no chance!

Comment: @FNG I have on declared something like this `ON a.id=b.fid`, also without the `SUM` functions my query would be useless! I indeed need them.

Comment: Add a where clause:  a.DateCol >= DATEADD(YEAR,-2,GETDATE()),  especially when tb1 has many history rows, in the past.

Comment: @Roman Doskoch if you use many times GETDATE() in same statement, there is geted only once per run.

Comment: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: @Fabio I added on related codes as well.

Comment: In SQL Management Studio, select "Query" -> "Show ACTUAL Execution Plan". Then run your query. When the query finishes, you should see a diagram. Please copy & paste this diagram. Thanks. edit: With the Execution Plan, you can improve speed by creating targeted indexes and re-creating stats. Therefore, please post the execution plan.

Comment: Again, please post the execution plan.

Comment: Still we are not seeing the `Execution Plan`. Please post it

Answer (score 9):

As it has been mentioned already, the [execution plan](https://developer.rackspace.com/blog/understanding-a-sql-server-execution-plan/) will be really helpful in this case. Based on what you've shown it seems you have extracted 12 columns of 15 total columns from `tb1 (a)`,
so you can try to run your query without any join and just against the `tb1` to see whether your query is working as expected. Since I can see nothing wrong with your SUM function calls, my best guess is you have an issue with your joins, I would suggest to do the following. You can start by excluding the last join for instance,
 `INNER JOIN tb5 e on c.col7 = e.id` and any related usage of it like `e.Class as [Class]` and `e.Class` in your group by statement. We are not going to exclude it completely, this is just a
test to make sure whether the problem is with that or not, if your query runs better and as expected you can try to use a temp table as a workaround instead of the last join, something
like this:

```sql
SELECT *
INTO #Temp
FROM
  (
     select * from tb5
  ) As tempTable;

SELECT 
    b.id as [ID]
    ,d.[Title] as [Title]
    ,e.Class as [Class]

    -- SUM Functions

FROM 
    tb1 a
INNER JOIN 
    tb2 b on a.id=b.fid and a.col3 = b.col4
INNER JOIN 
    tb3 c on b.fid = c.col5
INNER JOIN       
    tb4 d on c.id = d.col6
INNER JOIN 
    #Temp e on c.col7 = e.id
GROUP BY
    b.id, d.Title, e.Class
```

Actually, Temporary tables are tables that exist temporarily on the SQL Server. The temporary tables are useful for storing the immediate result sets that are accessed multiple times. You can read more about it here https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-temporary-tables/
And here https://codingsight.com/introduction-to-temporary-tables-in-sql-server/

Also I would strongly recommend, if you are using the Stored Procedure, set the `NOCOUNT` to `ON`, it can also provide a significant performance boost, because network traffic is greatly reduced:

```sql
SET NOCOUNT ON
SELECT *
INTO #Temp
-- The rest of code
```

Based on [this](https://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/56506/sql-server-set-nocount-on-statement-with-examples/):

> SET NOCOUNT ON is a set statement which prevents the message which shows the number of rows affected by T-SQL query statements. This is used within stored procedures and triggers to avoid showing the affected rows message. Using SET NOCOUNT ON within a stored procedure can improve the performance of the stored procedure by a significant margin.

Comment: Can you please explain why copying entire `tb5` to the `#Temp` table and joining the temp table work faster than joining `tb5` directly? surly they contain the same data (and the `#Temp` may be missing an index if it was existing in `tb5`). I really can't understand why this is more efficient (for all I know it should be less efficient to copy all data *and* join).

Comment: @zig You are right in this case, but what if the `tb5` is located in another server? In this case using a temp table is definitely faster than direct join to another server. That was just a suggestion to test and see whether anything is changed I had a similar situation in the past, and it seems fortunately the temp table has helped the OP also in this case.

Answer (score 3):

The best approach is to insert into a  table variable/hash table (if the row count is small use a table variable or use a  hash table if the row count is pretty much big).
Then update the aggregation and then finally select from the table variable or hash table. Looking into the query plan is necessary.

```
DECLARE @MYTABLE TABLE (ID INT, [Title] VARCHAR(500), [Class] VARCHAR(500),
[Current - Last 30 Days Col1] INT, [Current - Last 30 Days Col2] INT,
[Current - Last 90 Days Col1] INT,[Current - Last 90 Days Col2] INT,
[Current - Last 365 Days Col1] INT, [Current - Last 365 Days Col2] INT,
[Last year - Last 30 Days Col1] INT, [Last year - Last 30 Days Col2] INT,
[Last year - Last 90 Days Col1] INT, [Last year - Last 90 Days Col2] INT,
[Last year - Last 365 Days Col1] INT, [Last year - Last 365 Days Col2] INT)



INSERT INTO @MYTABLE(ID, [Title],[Class], 
[Current - Last 30 Days Col1], [Current - Last 30 Days Col2],
[Current - Last 90 Days Col1], [Current - Last 90 Days Col2],
[Current - Last 365 Days Col1], [Current - Last 365 Days Col2],
[Last year - Last 30 Days Col1], [Last year - Last 30 Days Col2],
[Last year - Last 90 Days Col1], [Last year - Last 90 Days Col2],
[Last year - Last 365 Days Col1], [Last year - Last 365 Days Col2]
  )
SELECT    b.id  ,d.[Title] ,e.Class ,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0        
FROM     tb1 a
INNER JOIN   tb2 b on a.id=b.fid and a.col3 = b.col4
INNER JOIN   tb3 c on b.fid = c.col5
INNER JOIN   tb4 d on c.id = d.col6
INNER JOIN  tb5 e on c.col7 = e.id
GROUP BY b.id, d.Title, e.Class

UPDATE T 
SET [Current - Last 30 Days Col1]=K.[Current - Last 30 Days Col1] , 
[Current - Last 30 Days Col2]    =K.[Current - Last 30 Days Col2],
[Current - Last 90 Days Col1]    = K.[Current - Last 90 Days Col1], 
[Current - Last 90 Days Col2]    =K.[Current - Last 90 Days Col2] ,
[Current - Last 365 Days Col1]   =K.[Current - Last 365 Days Col1], 
[Current - Last 365 Days Col2]   =K.[Current - Last 365 Days Col2],
[Last year - Last 30 Days Col1]  =K.[Last year - Last 30 Days Col1],
 [Last year - Last 30 Days Col2] =K.[Last year - Last 30 Days Col2],
[Last year - Last 90 Days Col1]  =K.[Last year - Last 90 Days Col1], 
[Last year - Last 90 Days Col2]  =K.[Last year - Last 90 Days Col2],
[Last year - Last 365 Days Col1] =K.[Last year - Last 365 Days Col1],
 [Last year - Last 365 Days Col2]=K.[Last year - Last 365 Days Col2]
    FROM @MYTABLE T JOIN 
     (
SELECT 
    b.id as [ID]
    ,ISNULL(Sum(CASE WHEN a.DateCol >= DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE()) THEN a.col1 ELSE 0 END),0) as [Current - Last 30 Days Col1]
    ,ISNULL(Sum(CASE WHEN a.DateCol >= DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE()) THEN a.col2 ELSE 0 END),0) as [Current - Last 30 Days Col2]

    ,ISNULL(Sum(CASE WHEN a.DateCol >= DATEADD(QUARTER,-1,GETDATE()) THEN a.col1 ELSE 0 END),0) as [Current - Last 90 Days Col1]
    ,ISNULL(Sum(CASE WHEN a.DateCol >= DATEADD(QUARTER,-1,GETDATE()) THEN a.col2 ELSE 0 END),0) as [Current - Last 90 Days Col2]

    ,ISNULL(Sum(CASE WHEN a.DateCol >= DATEADD(YEAR,-1,GETDATE()) THEN a.col1 ELSE 0 END),0) as [Current - Last 365 Days Col1]
    ,ISNULL(Sum(CASE WHEN a.DateCol >= DATEADD(YEAR,-1,GETDATE()) THEN a.col2 ELSE 0 END),0) as [Current - Last 365 Days Col2]

    ,ISNULL(Sum(CASE WHEN a.DateCol >= DATEADD(MONTH,-13,GETDATE()) and a.DateCol <= DATEADD(MONTH,-12,GETDATE()) THEN a.col1 ELSE 0 END),0) as [Last year - Last 30 Days Col1]
    ,ISNULL(Sum(CASE WHEN a.DateCol >= DATEADD(MONTH,-13,GETDATE()) and a.DateCol <= DATEADD(MONTH,-12,GETDATE()) THEN a.col2 ELSE 0 END),0) as [Last year - Last 30 Days Col2]

    ,ISNULL(Sum(CASE WHEN a.DateCol >= DATEADD(QUARTER,-5,GETDATE()) and a.DateCol <= DATEADD(QUARTER,-4,GETDATE()) THEN a.col1 ELSE 0 END),0) as [Last year - Last 90 Days Col1]
    ,ISNULL(Sum(CASE WHEN a.DateCol >= DATEADD(QUARTER,-5,GETDATE()) and a.DateCol <= DATEADD(QUARTER,-4,GETDATE()) THEN a.col2 ELSE 0 END),0) as [Last year - Last 90 Days Col2]

    ,ISNULL(Sum(CASE WHEN a.DateCol >= DATEADD(YEAR,-2,GETDATE()) and a.DateCol <= DATEADD(YEAR,-1,GETDATE()) THEN a.col1 ELSE 0 END),0) as [Last year - Last 365 Days Col1]
    ,ISNULL(Sum(CASE WHEN a.DateCol >= DATEADD(YEAR,-2,GETDATE()) and a.DateCol <= DATEADD(YEAR,-1,GETDATE()) THEN a.col2 ELSE 0 END),0) as [Last year - Last 365 Days Col2]
    FROM     tb1 a
INNER JOIN   tb2 b on a.id=b.fid and a.col3 = b.col4
INNER JOIN   tb3 c on b.fid = c.col5
INNER JOIN   tb4 d on c.id = d.col6
INNER JOIN  tb5 e on c.col7 = e.id
GROUP BY    b.id
) AS K ON T.ID=K.ID


SELECT *
FROM @MYTABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume tb1 is a large table (relative to tb2, tb3, tb4 and tb5).

If so, it makes sense here to restrict the selection of that table (with a WHERE clause).

If only a small part of tb1 is used, for example because the joins with tb2, tb3, tb4 and tb5 reduce the needed rows to just a few percent, then you should check if the tables are indexed on the columns you use in the joins.

If a large part of tb1 is used, then it can make sense to group its results before joining it to tb2, tb3, tb4 and tb5. Below is an example of that.

```
SELECT 
    b.id as [ID]
    ,d.[Title] as [Title]
    ,e.Class as [Class]
    ,SUM(a.[Current - Last 30 Days Col1]) AS [Current - Last 30 Days Col1]
    ,SUM(a.[Current - Last 30 Days Col2]) AS [Current - Last 30 Days Col2]
    ,SUM(a.[Current - Last 90 Days Col1]) AS [Current - Last 90 Days Col1]
    -- etc.
    FROM (
      SELECT a.id, a.col3

      ,Sum(CASE WHEN a.DateCol >= DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE()) THEN a.col1 ELSE 0 END) as [Current - Last 30 Days Col1]
      ,Sum(CASE WHEN a.DateCol >= DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE()) THEN a.col2 ELSE 0 END) as [Current - Last 30 Days Col2]

      ,Sum(CASE WHEN a.DateCol >= DATEADD(QUARTER,-1,GETDATE()) THEN a.col1 ELSE 0 END) as [Current - Last 90 Days Col1]
      ,Sum(CASE WHEN a.DateCol >= DATEADD(QUARTER,-1,GETDATE()) THEN a.col2 ELSE 0 END) as [Current - Last 90 Days Col2]

      ,Sum(CASE WHEN a.DateCol >= DATEADD(YEAR,-1,GETDATE()) THEN a.col1 ELSE 0 END) as [Current - Last 365 Days Col1]
      ,Sum(CASE WHEN a.DateCol >= DATEADD(YEAR,-1,GETDATE()) THEN a.col2 ELSE 0 END) as [Current - Last 365 Days Col2]

      ,Sum(CASE WHEN a.DateCol >= DATEADD(MONTH,-13,GETDATE()) and a.DateCol <= DATEADD(MONTH,-12,GETDATE()) THEN a.col1 ELSE 0 END) as [Last year - Last 30 Days Col1]
      ,Sum(CASE WHEN a.DateCol >= DATEADD(MONTH,-13,GETDATE()) and a.DateCol <= DATEADD(MONTH,-12,GETDATE()) THEN a.col2 ELSE 0 END) as [Last year - Last 30 Days Col2]

      ,Sum(CASE WHEN a.DateCol >= DATEADD(QUARTER,-5,GETDATE()) and a.DateCol <= DATEADD(QUARTER,-4,GETDATE()) THEN a.col1 ELSE 0 END) as [Last year - Last 90 Days Col1]
      ,Sum(CASE WHEN a.DateCol >= DATEADD(QUARTER,-5,GETDATE()) and a.DateCol <= DATEADD(QUARTER,-4,GETDATE()) THEN a.col2 ELSE 0 END) as [Last year - Last 90 Days Col2]

      ,Sum(CASE WHEN a.DateCol >= DATEADD(YEAR,-2,GETDATE()) and a.DateCol <= DATEADD(YEAR,-1,GETDATE()) THEN a.col1 ELSE 0 END) as [Last year - Last 365 Days Col1]
      ,Sum(CASE WHEN a.DateCol >= DATEADD(YEAR,-2,GETDATE()) and a.DateCol <= DATEADD(YEAR,-1,GETDATE()) THEN a.col2 ELSE 0 END) as [Last year - Last 365 Days Col2]

      FROM  tb1 a
      WHERE a.DateCol >= DATEADD(YEAR,-2,GETDATE())
      GROUP BY a.id, a.col3
    ) AS a
INNER JOIN 
    tb2 b on a.id=b.fid and a.col3 = b.col4
INNER JOIN 
    tb3 c on b.fid = c.col5
INNER JOIN       
    tb4 d on c.id = d.col6
INNER JOIN 
    tb5 e on c.col7 = e.id
GROUP BY
    b.id, d.Title, e.Class
```

Comment: It would be far better to first view the execution plan, and then to make decisions on creating indexes and recreating stats.

Comment: I really hate it that my post gets a negative score without any explanation why.

Of course I agree that to get to the heart of the performance issue, one has to inspect the execution plan.

Having said that, I stand by my recommendation about checking the indexes for any foreign keys that are relevant in the query.

Comment: You "assume" something without knowing. So you post an answer on basis of the unknown. Therefore downvote. It's better to instruct the OP to improve his question by posting the execution plan.

Comment: That's not all I wrote. Personally, I would only downvote if the answer is bad or wrong, not when I simply disagree. But thanks for responding.

Comment: In a way it is wrong, because how you can prove it is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Just use computed colums

**Example**

```
ALTER TABLE tb1 ADD [Current - Last 30 Days Col1] AS (CASE WHEN a.DateCol >= DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE()) THEN a.col1 ELSE 0 END) PERSISTED;
```

[Specify Computed Columns in a Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

For optimizing such calculations you man consider pre-calculating some of the values. The idea of pre-calculations is to reduce the number of rows that need to be read or proceed.

One way of achieving this is using an [indexed view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-ver15) and leave the engine to do the calculations by itself. As this type of views have some limitations, you man end up creating a simple table and perform the calculations instead. Basically, it depends on the business needs.

So, in the example below I am creating a table with `RowID` and `RowDatetime` columns and inserting 1 million rows. I am using an indexed view to count the entities per days, so instead of querying 1 million rows per year I will query 365 rows per year to count these metrics.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[DataSource];
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DataSource]
(
    [RowID] BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
   ,[RowDateTime] DATETIME2
);

GO

DROP VIEW IF EXISTS [dbo].[vw_DataSource];
GO

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_DataSource] WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT YEAR([RowDateTime]) AS [Year]
      ,MONTH([RowDateTime]) AS [Month]
      ,DAY([RowDateTime]) AS [Day]
      ,COUNT_BIG(*) AS [Count]
FROM [dbo].[DataSource]
GROUP BY YEAR([RowDateTime])
        ,MONTH([RowDateTime])
        ,DAY([RowDateTime]);
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_vw_DataSource] ON [dbo].[vw_DataSource]
(
    [Year] ASC,
    [Month] ASC,
    [Day] ASC
);

GO

DECLARE @min bigint, @max bigint
SELECT @Min=1 ,@Max=1000000

INSERT INTO [dbo].[DataSource] ([RowDateTime])
SELECT TOP (@Max-@Min+1) DATEFROMPARTS(2019,  1.0 + floor(12 * RAND(convert(varbinary, newid()))), 1.0 + floor(28 * RAND(convert(varbinary, newid())))          )       
FROM master..spt_values t1 
CROSS JOIN master..spt_values t2

GO


SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[vw_DataSource]


SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN DATEFROMPARTS([Year], [Month], [Day]) >= DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE()) THEN [Count] ELSE 0 END) as [Current - Last 30 Days Col1]
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN DATEFROMPARTS([Year], [Month], [Day]) >= DATEADD(QUARTER,-1,GETDATE()) THEN [Count] ELSE 0 END) as [Current - Last 90 Days Col1]
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN DATEFROMPARTS([Year], [Month], [Day]) >= DATEADD(YEAR,-1,GETDATE()) THEN [Count] ELSE 0 END) as [Current - Last 365 Days Col1]
FROM [dbo].[vw_DataSource];
```

The success of such solution depends very much on how the data is distributed and how many rows you have. For example, if you have one entry per day for each day of the year, the view and the table will have same match of rows, so the I/O operations will not be reduced.

Also, the above is just an example of materializing the data and reading it. In your case you may need to add more columns the view definition.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a lookup table "Dates" table to join my data to with an index on DatesId. I use the dates as a filter when I want to browse historical data. The join is fast and so it the filtering as the DatesId is clustered primary index (primary key). Add the date column (as included column) for your data table as well.

The dates table has the following columns:

DatesId, Date, Year, Quarter, YearQuarter, MonthNum, MonthNameShort, YearWeek, WeekNum, DayOfYear, DayOfMonth, DayNumOfWeek, DayName

Example data:
20310409    2031-04-09  2031    2   2031-Q2 4   April   Apr 2031_15 15  99  9   3   Wednesday

You can PM me if you want a csv of this so that you can import it to the database, but I'm sure you can easily find something like this online and make your own.

I add an identity column as well so that you can get an integer for each date. This makes it a bit easier to work with, but not a requirement.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.dates where dateIndex BETWEEN (getDateIndexDate(getDate())-30 AND getDateIndexDate(getDate())+0) --30 days ago
```

This allows me to easily jump back to a certain period. It's quite easy to create your own views on this. You can of course use the ROW_NUMBER() function to do this for years, weeks, etc. as well.

Once I have the daterange I want, I join to the data. Works very fast!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are always grouping values based on a whole number of months, I would first group by month in a subquery in the from clause. This is similar to using a temporary table. Not certain if this would actually speed up your query.

```sql
SELECT f.id, f.[Title], f.Class,
    SUM(CASE WHEN f.MonthDiff = 1 THEN col1 ELSE 0 END) as [Current - Last 30 Days Col1],
    -- etc
FROM (
    SELECT 
        b.id,
        d.[Title],
        e.Class,
        DateDiff(Month, a.DateCol, GETDATE()) as MonthDiff,
        Sum(a.col1) as col1,
        Sum(a.col2) as col2
    FROM  tb1 a
    INNER JOIN tb2 b on a.id = b.fid and a.col3 = b.col4
    INNER JOIN tb3 c on b.fid = c.col5
    INNER JOIN tb4 d on c.id = d.col6
    INNER JOIN tb5 e on c.col7 = e.id
    WHERE a.DateCol between DATEADD(YEAR,-2,GETDATE() and GETDATE()
    GROUP BY b.id, d.Title, e.Class, DateDiff(Month,  a.DateCol, GETDATE())
) f
group by f.id, f.[Title], f.Class
```

Answer (score -2):

To improve the speed of SQL query, you must add indexes. For each joined table, you have to add one index.

Like this code example for oracle:

```
CREATE INDEX supplier_idx
ON supplier (supplier_name);
```

Comment: this is not a bad suggestion.  you see from the OP that a temp table is created with no index - INNER JOIN  #Temp e on c.col7 = e.id.  while there is room for improvement in the answer, i don't think it should be downvoted en masse. particularly for a new user.

Comment: @smoore4 Agree, this option of downvoting without a clear argument should be removed. There's a big misuse of this functionality